# Delete Static Routes on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, ip, route

I have the following routes that I wish to delete:

```
10.250.0.0           10.250.0.37          UG        1          0
```

I have run the following to delete this with failure.

```
bash-3.2# route delete 10.250.0.0 -netmask 255.255.255.0 10.250.0.37
delete net 10.250.0.0: gateway 10.250.0.37: not in table
```

What is the cause for that failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Solaris `route` command, the delete, and add, sub-commands have the following syntax:

```
  route [ -fnvq ] cmd destination gateway [metric/netmask]
```

So you probably have more success with:

```
route delete 10.250.0.0 10.250.0.37 -netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Or to remove it permanently (as commented by @Alexandre Alves; assuming this was a permanent route):

```
route -p delete 10.250.0.0 10.250.0.37 -netmask 255.255.255.0
```

(Are you sure your netmask is correct for this class A ip-address?)

Comment: Thanks; it worked after changing the syntax and the netmask:

Comment: bash-3.2# route delete 10.250.0.0 10.250.0.37 -netmask 255.255.255.240
delete net 10.250.0.0: gateway 10.250.0.37

Comment: I have done a system reboot but the route is still on the route table? Which other file should i be deleting the Route from

Comment: I currently have no access to a Solaris machine to check, and I don't know by heart where this might be setup. Could you add the `route delete` line to `/etc/rc.local`, or is it pertinent that the route not even exists for a short period before rc.local is executed?

Comment: to remove a route permanently, you need to use the -p option. route -p delete

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the `-p` flag on your route command. This is what makes it persistent.

So rather than doing:

```
route delete 10.250.0.0 10.250.0.37 -netmask 255.255.255.0
```

you should be doing:

```
route -p delete 10.250.0.0 10.250.0.37 -netmask 255.255.255.0
```

If you don't use the `-p` flag when you delete then you'll just experience that the route is still there after you've rebooted (provided the route is persistent in the first place).

You can at any time see all routes with the `netstat -r` command and you can see persistent routes with the `route -p` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is very tricky which I noticed today to delete the route in Solaris 10 specifically.

You need to first run the command

```
route -p show
```

This will list all the persistent routes added in the system and also the command that was used to create them either for a host route or a network segment route. Otherwise, you are likely to get a message as "Not in File" after running the delete command.

Let me explain in the example below:

```
~# route -p show

 - persistent: route add host 10.47.118.111 10.47.89.1
 - persistent: route add 10.48.145.0/24 10.47.89.18
 - persistent: route add 10.50.21.0 10.47.89.32 -netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Here you see 3 different ways of adding a route has been used.

To delete the first route you need to use:

```
~# route -p delete host 10.47.118.111 10.47.89.1
```

Instead, if you run command:

```
# route -p delete 10.47.118.111/24 10.47.89.1
```

Assuming you had used correct netmask, still you cannot delete the persistent route in this command even though it seems correct command and end up getting message "not in file". This is usually flexible in Red Hat flavor so you can use any method to add/delete routes however not the case with Solaris 10 unsure of other versions or if any fixes.

Similarly to delete 2nd and 3rd persistent routes you need to exactly use:

```
~# route -p delete 10.48.145.0/24 10.47.89.18
~# route -p delete 10.50.21.0 10.47.89.32 -netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Hope this helps when you are clueless of what's happening :)

Comment: Apologies i am not familiar with using the formatting. Thanks @AdminBee. Looks good now.